# Can I change URL when UIWebview is loading ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview

I want to change URL when webview is loading,can I do that ? For example:if I find the URL is "www.google.com", I want to Change it and continute loading it . My code is :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
}
```

But I don't want to do like this:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)requestnavigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL isEqual:@"www.google.com"]) {
        [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com.hk"]]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Any other ways? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subclass UIWebView, and reimplement the loadRequest method, change if it match.

Comment: I think this is a good idea.Let me have a try.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: so what are you doing different when you reimplement loadRequest method? I mean still the url needs to be intercepted with -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)requestnavigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType and then call the customize loadrequest method

Comment: @wensj Do you mind show some bits of your sub class? Would be grateful!